# Moving multiple UIImageViews simultaneously

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview, quartz-graphics

simple question, 
I've got a superview holding multiple sub UIIMageViews that I'd like to move simultaneously.

I now about UIIView Animations but not how to launch multiples animation at a time.
Any clue about that ?

example animations would be : growing, shrinking, alpha changes, moving along different (radom generated) paths ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap them up in the same UIView Animation block, and all the changes will take place simultaneously.